# Configure Magento Cron fails

Tags: linux, unix, cron, magento2

Im trying to set a magento cron by doing the follow:

crontab -u magento2 -e

After that i press i for insert the tekst:

- - - - /usr/local/bin/php /home/magento2/public_html/magento2 cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
- - - - /usr/local/bin/php /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/update/cron.php >> /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/var/log/update.cron.log
- - - - /usr/local/bin/php /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/var/log/setup.cron.log

After that i press escape and type :x! to save the file.

Then the following msg appears:

"tmp/crontab.zchprf"3L, 46rC written
crontab: installing new crontab
"tmp/crontab.zchprf":1: bad day-of-week
errors in crontab file, can't install

Thanks for the help

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cron entry taking 5 values while you have typed * on 4 locations so giving error on saving cron. 
Use this in your cron

```
 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/magento2/public_html/magento2 cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /home/magento2/public_html/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
```